# Spark SQL RANK() over ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING fails

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I encountered a SQL clause which Spark SQL behaves differently (a bug?) from others (I compared with Hive).

You may copy and paste the following statements to test in hive shell.

```
hive>
CREATE TABLE t (v INT);
INSERT INTO t (v) VALUES (11), (21), (31), (42), (52);
SELECT v % 10 AS d, v, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY v % 10 ORDER BY v ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS rank FROM t;

hive>
```

The result shows what we expect.

```
1       11      1
1       21      2
1       31      3
2       42      1
2       52      2
```

However, when testing the following equivalent code in spark-shell,

```
scala>
Seq(11, 21, 31, 42, 52).toDF("v").createOrReplaceTempView("t")
spark.sql("SELECT v % 10 AS d, v, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY v % 10 ORDER BY v ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS rank FROM t").show

scala>
```

we get an exception.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window Frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING must match the required frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$applyOrElse$11.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$applyOrElse$11.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsDown$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:258)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsDown$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:258)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:279)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:293)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$6.apply(QueryPlan.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsDown(QueryPlan.scala:258)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:249)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$$anonfun$apply$30.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$$anonfun$apply$30.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2148)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$.apply(Analyzer.scala:2148)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$.apply(Analyzer.scala:2147)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
  ... 48 elided
```

This happens in both Spark 2.2.0 and Spark 2.3.0.

Is it a bug?  Or some misunderstanding of mine?

P.S.  I've also tested the following functions (by replacing RANK() in the clause).

```
ROW_NUMBER()    => same exception
DENSE_RANK()    => same exception
CUME_DIST()     => same exception
PERCENT_RANK()  => same exception
NTILE()         => same exception
LEAD(v)         => same exception
LAG(v)          => same exception
FIRST_VALUE(v)  => OK
LAST_VALUE(v)   => OK
COUNT(v)        => OK
SUM(v)          => OK
AVG(v)          => OK
MEAN(v)         => OK
MIN(v)          => OK
MAX(v)          => OK
VARIANCE(v)     => OK
STDDEV(v)       => OK
COLLECT_LIST(v) => OK
COLLECT_SET(v)  => OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ROW_NUMBER()    => same exception
> DENSE_RANK()    => same exception
> CUME_DIST()     => same exception
> PERCENT_RANK()  => same exception
> NTILE()         => same exception
> LEAD(v)         => same exception
> LAG(v)          => same exception
> ```

My first point is do you know why we use `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` ?

You have to first understand the concept of 
`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`.

It will return list of rows/records (between the frame of preceding value and following value). If you are using ROW_NUMBER()/Lead/LAG/ or the above analytical function for this, can you think what it will return. If you want to find just row number then why you are using 
`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`.

Your error says that the frame is not given properly.

Comment: If row_number() over ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUND AND CURRENT is n for some row, row_number() over ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUND AND UNBOUND should also be n.  Because openning the other boundary will not change the result of row_number().  You still count from 1 to n.

Comment: can you explain me what should be the output for row_number() over ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUND AND CURRENT? over ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUND AND CURRENT give us a list on which you are applying row_number(). what is the use of this? you want row number over partition on column d. you can get directly  why you want to use row_number() over ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUND AND CURRENT?

Comment: ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUND AND CURRENT is used by Spark. I see it in the error message.  It says U AND C mismatches U AND U, but I think their results should be the same.

Comment: I encountered this when I was doing an OHLC conversion on stock prices.  The LAST_VALUE(price) was over U AND C by default, which result was not what I want.  So I changed my window into U AND U then I encountered it.

Comment: I think you are getting confused. Take your time and go through the apache documentation. You will get a clear picture about this.

Comment: OK I see the point: if I say ROW_NUMBER() OVER ... ROWS -3 +3, it would be impossible to give the fixed numbers.  In the SQL documentation, these functions have only PARTITION BY and ORDER BY parts but no ROWS part.  Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. That'ts what I was trying to make you understand. It is great that now you are clear with this.